# Classic ASP WebForm Generator

Tags: forms, asp-classic

I'm newbie here and try to learn here.

I wanna create a Classic asp program, and it's contain a section that users can make their form ( like contact, register and so on).

Now question is, when form created ( inputs have their name and id )
How i can read and save them in DB ( here Access DB )

Is anybody here that know an example of Web Form generator?
Please help and guide me
thanks

Comment: Why are you starting a new project using a technology that has been dead for ten years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of a form element with using **Request.Form("element_name")**.

```
<%
    username = Request.Form("input-username")
    password = Request.Form("input-password")
%>
```

Considering that you know how to [connect access database](http://www.webwiz.co.uk/kb/asp-tutorials/connecting-to-an-access-database.htm), you can save above informations to database like:

```
<%
    Rs.AddNew()
    Rs("username") = username
    Rs("password") = password
    Rs.Update()
%>
```

**UPDATE**

To get, *dynamically created form* values, you will need to do **for each... loop** in Request.Form object.

```
<%
    for each item in Request.Form
        Response.Write item & "=" & Request.Form(item) & "<br />"
    next
%>
```

Also I suggest you to read this [article](http://www.devx.com/asp/Article/17745/0/).

Comment: at first thanks for your answer, but i knew it, you know what, as you said in your answer i must read data that posted by form, OK, in your example input have a name that you know like "input-username", but when user create a form, can assign any-name to input, how can get this? i cant use request.form because i don't know name of input!!

Comment: ok, now I understand what you mean. You can get "dynamically created form values" of course. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks man, that was so useful for me.